# Получение свойств JSF

Tags: java-ee, jsf, jboss

Доброе время суток, есть JSF-2 проект [ Netbeans 8 + JBoss as 7.1.1 + java ee 6 ] с двумя xhtml. Описание проблемы: При установке значения (переменной result) на одной странице и переходе на другую установленное значение не сохраняется, но если переменную result  сделать статической то сохраняется нормально. В java ee новичек если что-то еще надо намекните...
Вот код класса:

```
import java.io.Serializable; 
import javax.inject.Named;   
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@Named("users")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable { 
    private String result = "";

    public String getResult() { return result; }
    public void setResult(String newResult) { result = newResult; }
}
```

Вот стартовый xhtml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h:form>
         <h3>Please enter result</h3>   
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Name:</td>
               <td><h:inputText value="#{users.result}"/></td>
            </tr> 
         </table>
         <p><h:commandButton value="get"  action="welcome" /></p>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Вот второй xhtml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
       <h3>#{users.result}!</h3> 
  
   </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee       
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас конфликт аннотаций: одна из пакета `javax.inject`, другая из `javax.faces`. В результате жизненный цикл компонента становится неопределённым. Это связано с тем, что компонентами `javax.inject` должен управлять контейнер (сервер приложений), а компонентами `javax.faces` - фреймворк `JSF`. Если посмотреть под отладкой, то при каждом обращении к методам `UserBean` создаётся новый экземпляр класса, т.е., значение с формы ввода передаётся одному объекту, и после этого значение запрашивается уже у другого объекта (где оно пустое).

Решение проблемы: замените `@Named("users")` на `@ManagedBean(name = "users")` (из пакета `javax.faces.bean`). Альтернативный вариант: оставить `@Named("users")`, а `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` заменить на `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`.

Более подробно можно почитать в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012663/1341148) на англоязычном SO.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, Ваш ответ как бальзам на душу. Всех Вам земных благ!